# How to match 1000gm to 1kg in solr

Tags: solr

I am using solr 5.0,

I want to create some logical rule in solr like when i search for 1000gm it should match 1kg

I know about synoms in solr but in this case i can not use synoms directly because there can be something like 8000gm that needs to map 8kg

Comment: Is your query answered ?

Comment: Hi @SumeetSharma thanks for detailed answer but as of now handled this at application level but i will try your solution and will let you know , thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would have to write a custom filter for unit conversion logic.

You would need to tokenize using KeywordTokenizer and later apply a custom conversionFilterFactory to convert and save the indexed weights in a standard format. The same custom filter can be then used for querying and faceting.

You can have better idea from this [link](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Unit-of-dimension-for-solr-field-td4100209.html)

---

Implementation:

***UnitConversionTokenFilterFactory.java***

```
package com.solr.custom.filter.test;   
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;

/**
 * @author SumeetS
 *
 */
public class UnitConversionTokenFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public UnitConversionTokenFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
    super(args);
    if (!args.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown parameters: " + args);
    }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory#create(org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream)
     */
    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
    return new UnitConversionFilter(input);
    }

}
```

***UnitConversionFilter.java***

```
package com.solr.custom.filter.test;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;

/**
 * @author SumeetS
 *
 */
public class UnitConversionFilter extends TokenFilter{

    private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    /**
     * @param input
     */
    public UnitConversionFilter(TokenStream input) {
    super(input);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream#incrementToken()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
     if (input.incrementToken()) {
//        charUtils.toLowerCase(termAtt.buffer(), 0, termAtt.length());
         int length = termAtt.length();
         String inputWt = termAtt.toString(); //assuming format to be 1kg/mg
         float valInGrams = convertUnit(inputWt);
         String storeFormat = valInGrams+"";
         termAtt.setEmpty();
         termAtt.copyBuffer(storeFormat.toCharArray(), 0, storeFormat.length());
         return true;
        } else
          return false;
      }


    private float convertUnit(String field){
    String [] tmp = field.split("(k|m)?g");
    float weight = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
    String[] tmp2 = field.split(tmp[0]);
    String unit = tmp2[1];
    float convWt = 0;
    switch(unit) {
        case "kg":
        convWt = weight * 1000;
        break;
        case "mg":
        convWt = weight /1000;
        break;
        case "g":
        convWt = weight;
        break;
    }
    return convWt;    
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I haven't tested this. You would have to inject this into solr . You can refer [here](http://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/) for the same. `Make sure when you override ToeknFilterFactory and TokenFilter you convert the protected constructor to public` otherwise it will through `NoSuchMethodException` during `init`

**EDIT**

I deployed the above and its working fine.

Steps to deploy:

1. packaged it as a jar named customUnitConversionFilterFactory.jar and placed it under `<solrinstallation>/lib`
2. make below entry in the solrconfig.xml

   < lib dir="../../../lib/" regex=".*.jar" />
3. to your schema.xml add the custom field type and declare a field.

   < fieldType name="unitConversion" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100" >
   < analyzer >
   < tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
   < filter class="com.solr.custom.filter.test.UnitConversionTokenFilterFactory" />    < /analyzer >
   < /fieldType >

and

```
<field name="unitConversion" type="unitConversion" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

4. From solr console add solr docs

[image: add doc]

5. Try out queries:

   http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*%3A*&fq=unitConversion%3A1kg&wt=json&indent=true

   response:

   {
     "responseHeader":{
       "status":0,
       "QTime":0,
       "params":{
         "q":"*:*",
         "indent":"true",
         "fq":"unitConversion:1kg",
         "wt":"json"}},
     "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
         {
           "id":"temp1",
           "unitConversion":"1kg",
           "*version*":1524406802172608512},
         {
           "id":"tmp2",
           "unitConversion":"1000g",
           "*version*":1524406843026178048},
         {
           "id":"tmp3",
           "unitConversion":"1000000mg",
           "*version*":1524407318865772544}]
     }}

AND

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=*%3A*&fq=unitConversion%3A2kg&wt=json&indent=true

response: 

    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "fq":"unitConversion:2kg",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"tmp4",
        "unitConversion":"2kg",
        "_version_":1524407426310209536}]
  }}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and very well documented answer , great job